# Active Directory windows 2012

Tags: windows-8, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have problem with windows 2012 active directory. one of the client machine which is windows 8 could not login to active directory we need to close network connection to login windows 8 local and turn network on again.it was working properly and suddenly this client stop to work. it is little bit strange to me I am really new to active directory staff and I don't have any clue what to do. if you had anything like it before I would like to hear your experience and solution. btw sorry for my English 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing the client from the domain and re-joining it? Also check the date and time of the client. Also make sure the client hasn't got the same hostname as another client.

Comment: You should try a system restore, that way You can find out if it is something from the server of from the local PC.

Comment: Is this problem specific to a single user or multiple users on that computer ? What error do you get when it fails ?

Comment: thanks for the comments, I got error message as "invalid login credential" it is only one user and also with that user account we can not login from another client either

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with that user account then.

Comment: yes but how can I fix it I don't know I already try to change password on the server and client as well but it didn't work. when I unplug network cable from client it is login without problem but I am sure the password for this user is the same with client

Comment: Hello guys, I sort the problem, **it was a password problem when I change the password from server client started to connect without any problem**. sorry about misleading I said that password on client and server are same, people working there they told me that they already change the password on the server and the client, anyways thanks for your support I really appreciated